# Excel VBA - Concatenate Rows with duplicate KEY values

Tags: vba, excel, spss

I have a very large set of data in the following format:

**Before**

[image]

I'm brand new to VBA, but I'm working towards conforming this data so that it can be entered into SPSS. For our purposes, it needs to look like this:

**After**

[image]

The idea being that all rows with matching ID Number are combined into a single row of *n* length. As illustrated, the number of rows are not consistent. Additionally, we need to be able to handle blank cells -- in some cases, Value or Length may not be entered, but the next row down needs to begin in the correct location per the headers.

I've done this a number of times in Bash, but my wife needs to be able to reproduce this on her own, as there are a number of spreadsheets with data of this type.

I'm currently figuring out syntax and writing this out, and my initial approach is to filter for unique IDs, copy to a second sheet, then do a For Each loop to append the data.

I'd paste my code, but it would serve more as a distraction in its current phase than anything useful. Any insight regarding methodology for this would be much appreciated, especially if there is an easier or less taxing way to do it.

Thanks for reading!
Mike

Comment: How does this become usable data in SPSS? The column headers are not unique.  It would be helpful to show your code (that is what's expected of you here -- because it is much easier for someone to offer assistance by *modifying* your existing code than by writing it from scratch).  Cheers.

Comment: I would probably look at iteration over the rows, building a delimited string (comma or tab delimited) to represent each "row" in the formatted output, based on the ID, and then write that out to a TXT file that could easily be read by SPSS.

Comment: David, you're correct. The headers in the actual file will be unique, specifically: Type_1, Value_1, Type_2, Value_2, etc.

I'm working on code right now. Thanks for the suggestions -- that makes a lot of sense. Once I have something that is actually legible, I'll post it.

Comment: OK, well when you can share the code that you have, I'd be happy to assist. This should be fairly straightforward using a Dictionary object.  Probably less than 30 lines of code.

Comment: Not a constructive comment, @Andrew

Comment: Yes, the format isn't ideal. I've updated the second image to show more accurately the end goal.

For context, this is a grant-based study that my wife is working on, and the data formatting was established by someone other than her. I'm working on this to make her life easier -- to turn what is literally days of manual labor into a few quick macros.

OKay. Going to work on code. I'll be back. Thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: Can I ask why you're bothering to pre-process the file before importing it into SPSS?  What you're after is a simple change from long format to wide format, something that SPSS can do natively with the CASESTOVARS command.  After the raw data is imported and sorted if needed, the full command based on the example data provided would simply be 'casestovars / id = id / groupby = variable.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method I described in my comment above:

> I would probably look at iteration over the rows, building a delimited string (comma or tab delimited) to represent each "row" in the formatted output, based on the ID, and then write that out to a TXT file that could easily be read by SPSS

Here's the code. It is slightly more than the 30 lines I estimated :)

```
Sub FormatDataFileForSPSS()
Dim rng As Range            'the range representing the entire set of data to be formatted
Dim r As Range              'row iterator for the data table
Dim key As Variant          'id number
Dim rowData As String       'concatenated row data
Dim outputPath As String    'the place to put the output file
Dim outputFile As String    'the file name

'--- REQUIRES REFERENCE TO MICROSOFT SCRIPTING RUNTIME ---
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary 'a dictionary that we will use to concat each row by ID
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject 'used to write the output file

'Begin procedure here...

'Allow the user to select a range of data to format
' do NOT select the "header" row!
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select the data to be formatted", "Select Data", Type:=8)

'Create the dictionary:
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'get the destination for the output file:
outputPath = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") 'Or modify to use a different filepath
outputFile = outputPath & "\my output.txt" 'Modify as needed

'Iterate the data table:
For Each r In rng.Rows
    'get the key value
    key = r.Cells(1, 1).Value
    'Concatenate the row data to a string
    rowData = r.Cells(1, 2) & vbTab & r.Cells(1, 3) & vbTab & r.Cells(1, 4) & vbTab & r.Cells(1, 5)
    'Check if this KEY value already exists
    If Not dict.Exists(key) Then
        'if not, then add it to the dictionary
        dict.Add key, rowData
    Else:
        'Append to the existing key's value:
        dict(key) = dict(key) & vbTab & rowData
    End If
Next

'Create our FileSystemObject to write the text file:
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
With fso.CreateTextFile(Filename:=outputFile, overwrite:=True, unicode:=False)
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        .WriteLine dict(key)
    Next
    .Close
End With

End Sub
```

Output as tab-delimited, without header row (since the headers in your example aren't unique to begin with).  I am fairly certain that you can specify in SPSS to import the data without header row, and it will assign default variable names that you can later modify if needed.

[image]

Here is the data when viewed in SPSS (follow prompts to open delimited text file)

[image]

Or you can open the TXT delmited file in Excel and follow a few prompts, specifying it as Tab-delimited, then you could add the header information in the Excel file:

[image]

Comment: David!

Thanks for your suggested fix! This is a much more elegant solution than what I'm looking at.

I'm going to test it now, and I'll let you know my results!

-Mike

Comment: There's more than one way to solve most problems, and while copying data, creating new worksheets, filtering, etc., is one possible solution, it's really brute force :)  The benefit to that method is that novice/new VBA folk would almost immediately understand because it would use "basic" methods and actions obtainable from the Macro Recorder, but it would be slower, clunkier, etc.  Cheers!